# How to dynamically add input fields on user selected option in multiple select type

Tags: javascript, html

i am working with select type with multiple attribute and want to display as much as input field as options selected and remove the input field if selected option is unselected but the output of my code is showing only one input field.
here is the code

```js
function check(skill) {
  if (skill.value == "css") {
    document.getElementById("css").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("css").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (skill.value == "php") {
    document.getElementById("php").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("php").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (skill.value == "magento") {
    document.getElementById("magento").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("magento").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple onchange="check(this);">
  <option value="css">css</option>
  <option value="php">php</option>
  <option value="magento">magento</option>
</select>
<div id="css" style="display: none;">
  <label for="sel1"></label><input type="text" name="css" id="selc1">
</div>
<div id="php" style="display: none;">
  <label for="sel2"></label><input type="text" name="php" id="selc2">
</div>
<div id="magento" style="display: none;">
  <label for="sel3"></label><input type="text" name="magento" id="selc3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery `val` to get the value of the multiselect. This will return an array. Instead on inline style use a class `hide` to hide all the elements. Use another class `techInput` to target the inputs. On selection of an option iterate through the elements have this `techInput` class and get its id to check if the multiselect array have this `id`. If the array have this id , it mean that option is selected then use `removeClass` to remove the `hide`

```js
function check(skill) {
  const selectedSkils = $(skill).val();
  $('.techInput').each(function(i, v) {
    if (selectedSkils.indexOf($(v).attr('id')) !== -1) {
      $(v).removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $(v).addClass('hide')
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.techInput {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple onchange="check(this);">
  <option value="css">css</option>
  <option value="php">php</option>
  <option value="magento">magento</option>
</select>
<div id="css" class='hide techInput'>
  <label for="sel1"></label><input type="text" name="css" id="selc1" placeholder='css'>
</div>
<div id="php" class='hide techInput'>
  <label for="sel2"></label><input type="text" name="php" placeholder='php' id="selc2">
</div>
<div id="magento" class='hide techInput'>
  <label for="sel3"></label><input placeholder='magento' type="text" name="magento" id="selc3">
</div>
```